# Не получается собрать OpenSSL

Tags: c++, mingw, openssl, conan

Начинаю изучать C++ (перешел с Java, Kotlin), накидал простой код для отправки GET запросов. Из под Ubuntu все собирается отлично. Но захотел сбилдить из под винды.

> Билдю этой командой **(На этом этапе ошибка)**

```
set CC=gcc
set CXX=g++
conan install --build=openssl --build=libcurl ..
```

> Логи команды выше

[Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/GxtqmP7M)

> Содержание файла conanfile.txt

```
[requires]
libcurl/7.75.0

[generators]
cmake
```

> Содержание файла CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)

project(cpptestproject)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -std=c11")

include(${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/conanbuildinfo.cmake)
conan_basic_setup()

file(GLOB CPPS "src/*.cpp")

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${CPPS})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${CONAN_LIBS})
```

> g++ -v

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\winlibs-llvm-free\tools\mingw64\bin\g++.exe
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=c:/programdata/chocolatey/lib/winlibs-llvm-free/tools/mingw64/bin/../libexec/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/lto-wrapper.exe
OFFLOAD_TARGET_NAMES=nvptx-none
Target: x86_64-w64-mingw32
Configured with: ../configure --prefix=/R/winlibs64_stage/_TMP_/inst_gcc-10.2.0/share/gcc --build=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --host=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --with-pkgversion='MinGW-W64 x86_64-posix-seh, built by Brecht Sanders' --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --enable-threads=posix --disable-sjlj-exceptions --disable-libunwind-exceptions --disable-serial-configure --disable-bootstrap --enable-host-shared --enable-plugin --disable-default-ssp --disable-rpath --disable-libstdcxx-pch --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --disable-libstdcxx-debug --disable-version-specific-runtime-libs --with-stabs --disable-symvers --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,lto,objc,obj-c++,d --disable-gold --disable-nls --disable-stage1-checking --disable-win32-registry --disable-multilib --enable-ld --enable-libquadmath --enable-libada --enable-libssp --enable-libstdcxx --enable-lto --enable-fully-dynamic-string --enable-libgomp --enable-graphite --enable-mingw-wildcard --with-mpc=/d/Prog/winlibs64_stage/custombuilt --with-mpfr=/d/Prog/winlibs64_stage/custombuilt --with-gmp=/d/Prog/winlibs64_stage/custombuilt --with-isl=/d/Prog/winlibs64_stage/custombuilt --enable-install-libiberty --enable-__cxa_atexit --without-included-gettext --with-diagnostics-color=auto --with-libiconv --with-system-zlib --with-build-sysroot=/R/winlibs64_stage/_TMP_/gcc-10.2.0/build_mingw/mingw-w64 CFLAGS=-I/d/Prog/winlibs64_stage/custombuilt/include/libdl-win32 --enable-offload-targets=nvptx-none
Thread model: posix
Supported LTO compression algorithms: zlib zstd
gcc version 10.2.0 (MinGW-W64 x86_64-posix-seh, built by Brecht Sanders)
```

> gcc -v

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\winlibs-llvm-free\tools\mingw64\bin\gcc.exe
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=c:/programdata/chocolatey/lib/winlibs-llvm-free/tools/mingw64/bin/../libexec/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/lto-wrapper.exe
OFFLOAD_TARGET_NAMES=nvptx-none
Target: x86_64-w64-mingw32
Configured with: ../configure --prefix=/R/winlibs64_stage/_TMP_/inst_gcc-10.2.0/share/gcc --build=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --host=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --with-pkgversion='MinGW-W64 x86_64-posix-seh, built by Brecht Sanders' --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --enable-threads=posix --disable-sjlj-exceptions --disable-libunwind-exceptions --disable-serial-configure --disable-bootstrap --enable-host-shared --enable-plugin --disable-default-ssp --disable-rpath --disable-libstdcxx-pch --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --disable-libstdcxx-debug --disable-version-specific-runtime-libs --with-stabs --disable-symvers --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,lto,objc,obj-c++,d --disable-gold --disable-nls --disable-stage1-checking --disable-win32-registry --disable-multilib --enable-ld --enable-libquadmath --enable-libada --enable-libssp --enable-libstdcxx --enable-lto --enable-fully-dynamic-string --enable-libgomp --enable-graphite --enable-mingw-wildcard --with-mpc=/d/Prog/winlibs64_stage/custombuilt --with-mpfr=/d/Prog/winlibs64_stage/custombuilt --with-gmp=/d/Prog/winlibs64_stage/custombuilt --with-isl=/d/Prog/winlibs64_stage/custombuilt --enable-install-libiberty --enable-__cxa_atexit --without-included-gettext --with-diagnostics-color=auto --with-libiconv --with-system-zlib --with-build-sysroot=/R/winlibs64_stage/_TMP_/gcc-10.2.0/build_mingw/mingw-w64 CFLAGS=-I/d/Prog/winlibs64_stage/custombuilt/include/libdl-win32 --enable-offload-targets=nvptx-none
Thread model: posix
Supported LTO compression algorithms: zlib zstd
gcc version 10.2.0 (MinGW-W64 x86_64-posix-seh, built by Brecht Sanders)
```

> conan -v

```
Conan version 1.35.0
```

> cmake --version

```
cmake version 3.20.0
```

> make -v

```
GNU Make 4.3
Built for Windows32
Copyright (C) 1988-2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

Comment: Чтобы не собирать openssl, его можно поставить уже готовый из MSYS2.

Comment: Не слышал про MSYS2. Это что-то вроде коллекции библиотек?

Comment: Но все же надо разобраться из-за чего возникает ошибка при компиляции

Comment: Грубо говоря это пакетный менеджер с библиотеками, компиляторами и прочим, а также с портами с линукса консольных утилит типа bash, make, и т.п.

Comment: Все еще не решает мою проблему. Попробовал установить OpenSSL в MSYS2, но conan все еще его требует и не может собрать

Comment: я вас категорически приветсвую!
ошибка такая же как https://github.com/openssl/openssl/issues/8268
происходит из-за того, что CC=gcc указывает на первый попавшийся gcc.exe из PATH, который резолвится в gcc из MSYS2 - не тот что ожидается.
можно либо указать полный путь до gcc.exe, чтобы устранить неодназначность, либо попытаться собрать OpenSSL без использования DSO (указанием опции -o openssl:no_dso=True)

Comment: *"conan все еще его требует"* А вам вообще нужен этот Conan? MSYS2 самодостаточный.

Answer (score 0):

Добавил в параметры `-o openssl:no_dso=True`
Теперь собираю библиотеки этой командой

```
set CC=gcc
set CXX=g++
conan install --build=openssl --build=libcurl ..
```